# Does BTRFS scrub examine subvolume or the device that subvolume resides on?

Tags: btrfs

Btrfs `scrub` takes the mountpoint as its target. We can identify the possible btrfs targets by:

```bsh
while read d m t x
do
  [[ $t != "btrfs" ]] && continue
  echo "To be scrubbed: $m"
done < /proc/mounts
```

However, we can mount a btrfs subvolume like a regular device. As we can have many subvolumes on the same device, scrubbing all mount points with btrfs file system type may lead to many duplicate examinations.

If `btrfs scrub` examines the underlying device when the mountpoint is given, we could filter the `/proc/mounts` output unique by device path:

```
<(cat /proc/mounts | sort -u -k1,1)
```

Is scrub intended to run per device or per subvolume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by the [docs,](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-scrub.html) the scrub command operates on a whole filesystem. This refers to the entire filesystem that was created with mkfs. Although [subvolumes](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-subvolume.html) can be mounted on their own, they are still part of the main filesystem, some options and operations such as scrub are only valid for the whole filesystem, not just a specific subvolume:

> Subvolumes belong to a single filesystem and as implemented now all share the same specific mount options